# MacOS High Sierra Uninstall All Postgres

Tags: postgresql, macos-high-sierra

I had `PostgreSQL 9.6` installed and upgraded my gems.  Then `10.x` was installed along with `9.6` and confusion set in.

I had little data which I backed up.  I want to get rid of both and start fresh.  I uninstalled using:

```
brew uninstall postgresql@10
```

...and there is no `postgresql` in `brew list`.  But the `9.6` is still running, but not showing up in this list.

How can I kill the remnants and start again?  Here's the evidence from `top`:

```
32147  postgres     0.0   00:00.13 1     0    8     1608K  0B     4696K  32147 105   sleeping *0[1]            0.00000 0.00000    14551
32140  postgres     0.0   00:00.04 1     0    8     1492K  0B     1748K  32140 105   sleeping *0[1]            0.00000 0.00000    14551
```

I know killing the processes will not take care of the startup later on.  I have recorded the output of `show all;` so I can delete files, but I'm not clear as to where to look or what I'm looking for.

Comment: I found /Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/uninstall-postgresql.app which seems to have done some major cleaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That app worked, plus some other removals in the `terminal`:

```
sudo rm /etc/postgres-reg.ini
sudo rm -rf /Library/PostgreSQL/
```

Everything looks good.